# How can I make SDL output displaying with audio stream in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-output, directshow, sdl

Learning ffmpeg, I tested SDL output by the code below. I noticed that video played well but no audio.

```
ffmpeg -re -i INPUT -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_size qcif -f sdl "sdl out"
```

there was no sound. audio stream was not appeared in the sdl output, but only the video stream.

How can I make sdl output take audio stream as well as video stream? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. The SDL audio muxer is only implemented in ffplay.

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg -re -i INPUT -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_size qcif -f sdl "sdl out" -f pulse "pulse out"
```

Comment: So can you explain this answer? Does the command work? Comparing it to what the original poster has posted it seems like your command adds `-f pulse "pulse out"` to the end of the command. Can you explain why that would work here?